# How to use FFMPEG to add moov to the begining of the file?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, mp4, webm

I am saving a webm file from a `buffer` array as such :

```
const stream = Readable.from(buffer);
       
 
ffmpeg().input(stream).videoCodec('libx264').audioCodec('libfaac').format('webm').outputOptions([
                "-movflags", "+faststart",
                "-preset", "veryfast",
                "-crf", "30", "-threads 5"
              ])
```

and despite using `"-movflags"` the video file doesn't present metadata especially the duration of the video on remote buffer playing. How can I add metadata information of duration to the written file?

Comment: You're confusing... Is `stream` a Webm or a MP4 content? MOOV exists in MP4. Try as:
`.input(stream).videoCodec('copy').audioCodec('copy').format('mp4').`

Comment: @VC.One I did try it with copy and mp4 and I guess I am getting the same results. Here is an example of the recorded file : https://v2.globalassessment.com.tr/api/videos/zzz-82-ALL.mp4

Comment: The file you linked does [have MOOV at the beginning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AtfZ.png). Is it the output of the command? If yes, then your problem about MOOV is solved. The file played correctly in Chrome browser on Windows (I tested on Windows and also did not test with other browsers). Are you getting any playback issues yourself?

Comment: PS: Ideally you always want to output as MP4 since that plays everywhere without issues. **(1)** If you got MP4 with MOOV at back, then use the "copy" command to re-arrange (is fast process). **(2)** If you get a recorded WebM then it must be converted, your own shown command should work if the input variable **stream** is of Webm video/data. Simply change this part `.format('webm').` to become as `.format('mp4').` then it can appy the `movflags` etc options to the MP4 output from Webm input. Encoding new bytes is slower than moving already existing bytes...

Comment: @VC.One Thanks for all the effort you have put into my question. My issue with the file is when I load it remotely I have to wait for the entire file to load in order to play and I wish to play it right from what it has buffered. I thought that is a MOOV related issue but since you say the MOOV is in the beginning, I am not sure how I can play the file from the buffer instead of waiting for the entire file to load. I did make those changes to MP4 and I am gonna keep it that way with       ffmpeg().input(stream).videoCodec('copy').audioCodec('copy').format('mp4').outputOptions([,